# "Rollback process" for different penetration testing in case of something goes wrong?

Tags: penetration-test, exploit, vulnerability, vulnerability-scanners, recovery

In some extent, different kind of vulnerability assessment and penetration testing may impact on target system. I am looking for the solution/rollback process if something goes wrong during test.

For example, to check the stress absorbing capacity of any server DoS attack testing might me one solution. During DoS/DDoS attack target system may be interrupted in service or totally shut down. In this case, we need to pause the testing or decrease the amount of packets sent to the target system. Additionally we can restart our clients targeted server if any change happen which might impact the service of the target machines.

I am not sure I have make an example of rollback process/procedure for a part of vulnerability assessment. 
By the way, if anyone knows some other rollback process might be necessary during/after vulnerability assessment and penetration testing, please give me your valued opinion/suggestion regarding this issue.

Comment: It is kind of hard for me to understand what you are asking. If you are asking about rolling back in the sense of the state/data of the machine then this might be better asked on Server Fault. Otherwise you can't really undo a DDoS attack. The damaged of spent resources is permanent. I know for online video games rollbacks have been done since characters might of suffered from item/xp loss due to death. Otherwise, rolling back procedures are going to depend on your situation, tech stack, if there is a need to rollback, etc. So currently it is too broad/difficult to answer.

Comment: @baconface, You understood exactly what i am asking. As part of Vulnerability assessment and penetration testing service penetration testers have to give Rollback process in case something goes wrong during test. 
And, Yes, i am gonna post it to Server Fault also. Thanks for the info! :)

Comment: It sounds like you are pen testing a live system. This is a very bad thing to do. The typical way to handle "rollback" is to pen test on a non-production environment and then just not care if you break things.

Comment: Also, please do not cross post. Flag your question and ask a mod to migrate.